# Testar se todos os caracteres da primeira string também aparecem na segunda

Tags: c, string

Estou a tentar fazer essa função com a ajuda das funções `strcmp()` e `strncmp()` e não estou a ter grande sucesso.

Imaginemos que tenho a string `char s[] = "abc"` e outra string `char v[] = "cdeabf"` , o *output* daria 0 (valor verdadeiro) pois os caracteres [`a`, `b` e `c`] pertencem a `v`. Caso contrário daria -1 (valor falso).

Se houver uma função pré-definida que me ajude, qual seria? E se der para fazer esta função sem ajuda de funções pré-definidas, como faria?

Comment: Você sabe o tamanho das strings? Dei uma resposta que não usa nenhuma função pré-definida *exceto* pela `strlen` (pois caso contrário não teria como saber qual o tamanho das strings). Mas se você já souber esses valores de antemão, aí não precisa...

Comment: @mgibsonbr embora eu tenha entendido a intenção do comentário tenho que dizer que é possível descobrir o tamanho da *string* sem uma função pré-definida, basta você escrever um código que faça exatamente o que a `strlen` faz :P Algo assim:  `const char *s; for (s = suaString; *s; ++s); int tamanho = s - suaString;`. Só a título de curiosidade.

Comment: @bigown haha é claro, falha minha! O que a `strlen` faz é justamente contar os caracteres até - mas sem incluir - o terminador nulo, facinho de fazer à mão se necessário... :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<strike>Não existe nada pronto mas</strike>(ver abaixo) não é difícil criar uma função que faça isto. Se entendi o que você deseja, seria isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int contem(char s1[], char s2[]) {
    for (int i = 0; s2[i]; i++) {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; s1[j]; j++) if(s2[i] == s1[j]) break;
        if (s1[j] == '\0') return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    char s[] = "abc";
    char v[] = "cdeabf";
     if (contem(v, s)) printf("'%s' contém todos os caracteres presentes em '%s'", v, s);
     else printf("'%s' não contém todos os caracteres presentes em '%s'", v, s);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ILusne). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lsgootga-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/CharsExists.c).

Fica aí a solução para quem quer fazer na mão. Mas existe uma forma de alcançar o mesmo resultado conforme a resposta do JJoao. A função [`strspn`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html) retorna o tamanho da *string* sendo comparada se todos os caracteres estiverem presentes na outra *string*. Então fica fácil identificar o que se pede na pergunta. Usando função pronta ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char s[] = "abc";
    char v[] = "cdeabf";
    printf("'%s' %scontém todos os caracteres presentes em '%s'", v, (strspn(s, v) == strlen(s)) ? "" : "não ", s);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/c4jJol). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ldwppwme-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/CharsExists2.c).

Comment: Só não percebi uma coisa @bigown , qual o papel da variável j nesse caso? Obrigado pela resposta ;)

Comment: @JoséCunha coloquei alguns comentário. O `j` é só a variável de controle do índice da *string*. Ele vai variando para andar caractere por caractere na *string*. Isto esclarece o que queria saber? Eu vi que você tinha aceitando minha resposta e depois trocou para a outra que fornece uma solução parecida, tanto que votei nela. Só fiquei na dúvida se você o fez porque depois viu que preferiu a outra ou foi sem querer e não percebeu que só pode aceitar uma resposta como a que mais ajudou você. Você poderá votar em todas as respostas e perguntas do *site* assim que tiver reputação suficiente.[tour]

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento @bigown ;) Não sabia que se podia apenas aceitar uma resposta xD . De qualquer maneira , gostei muito dos comentários e da estrutura o que torna fácil a  leitura! Obrigado pela Ajuda! ;)

Comment: Não recomendo usar strlen dentro de loops, como você fez em `if (j == strlen(s1)) {`. strlen é uma operação cara, que leva tempo O(n) e nem sempre o compilador consegue ser esperto o suficiente para otimizá-la. No seu caso seria melhor usar `s1[j]` igual você já faz no for. Ou que sabe até trocar esses ifs e o break por um uso esperto de goto.

Comment: @hugomg tem razão, fiz correndo e nem me preocupei com isto mas vou melhorar isto. Não quis usar o `goto` para não provocar ataques epiléticos em alguns programadores :D

Answer (score 15):

Como referido por @mgibsonbr, a convenção C é 0 para falso, diferente de zero para verdadeiro.

Usando essa convenção, eu faria simplesmente:

```
...
return (strspn(s,aceitar) == strlen(s));
```

**Edit: Explicação sumária**: de acordo com o manual, capítulo das funções sobre strings:

```
$ man string.h 
....
size_t strspn(const char *s, const char *accept);
   Calculate the length of the starting segment in the string s that consists 
   entirely of bytes in accept.
```

temos uma função `strspn` ([Ver detalhes aqui](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strspn.htm)) que pode ajudar:

se todos os caracteres da string inicial estiverem na lista dos caracteres a aceitar, a função `strspn(s,aceitar)` devolverá o comprimento da string s (=todos).

Para a nossa questão, basta portanto comparar o número de caracteres aceites com `strlen(s)`

---

Obrigado ao @mgibsonbr pela ajuda com a explicação

Comment: Resposta excelente! Estou oferecendo uma recompensa pra ela. Contudo, seria desejável uma referência pra função `strspn` ([exemplo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strspn.htm)), e talvez explicar o que ela faz.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário e pela sugestão de explicar melhor... (sou sempre um pouco trapalhão nestas coisas).

Comment: Está muito boa a resposta @JJoao :). Obrigado pela explicação! ;)

Comment: Quando vi a resposta inicial fiquei pasmo, excelente!

Comment: @mgibsonbr obrigado pelo link (que vou incluir na explicação).

Comment: Você pode colocar um código mostrando isto funcionando de acordo com o que a pergunta pede? Ou não entendi sua resposta ou ela não funciona.

Comment: Acho que o @bigown tem razão, vejam no [ideone](http://ideone.com/kZVaYa)

Comment: @JorgeB. se for isto mesmo, e eu já tinha feito este teste, as pessoas estão votando em uma resposta errada que é facilmente verificável mas que ninguém se deu ao trabalho antes de votar. O voto deve ser dado quando você sabe que a solução é boa e funciona, não porque ela é curiosa.

Comment: @bigown acho que foi erro de digitação. Eu mesmo para fazer o teste dei 1000 voltas com o 'v' e o 's'. Até porque a explicação está direita.

Comment: @JJoao será `return (strspn(s,v) == strlen(s));`?

Comment: @JorgeB. Desculpem a minha baralhada: se calhar  mudei os ids: o que eu quero dizer é obviamente `return (strspn(str_a_testar,aceites) == strlen(str_a_testar));`

Comment: @bigown: muito obrigado pela observação (sou um burro!) -- ao editar as propostas de solução, não vemos simultaneamente o texto da pergunta e mudei os nomes. De acordo com as vossas observações, alterei os ids de modo a ficar mais legivel e de acordo com os ids da explicação.

Comment: @bigown De fato, o `s` e o `v` estavam trocados. Eu confesso que também não **testei** o código - confiando que uma única linha de código cuja semântica era clara, e a documentação precisa, podia ser entendida só com minha cabeça. E de fato, o bug estava nas variáveis de nomes pouco descritivos, não na lógica da solução. No fim o maior erro foi meu, por ter sido quem chamou a atenção pra resposta sem verificá-la com mais cuidado (ainda darei a recompensa pra ela, entretanto, pela lógica em si). Hehe lembrei na hora do [Knuth](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/d/donaldknut181622.html) :P

Comment: @mgibsonbr, (1) muito obrigado pelo +100, até estou sensibilizado! (eu sou um burro e não sabia o que era uma "recompensa"). (2) muito obrigado por partilhares connosco o "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it."

Answer (score 10):

Como comparar caracteres é fácil (basta usar o operador de igualdade - `==`), minha sugestão é simplesmente percorrer cada caractere de uma e da outra string verificando se eles são iguais:

```
// No cabeçalho:

#define VERDADEIRO 0
#define FALSO -1

// Na sua função:

int ts = strlen(s); // Tamanho da primeira string
int tv = strlen(v): // Tamanho da segunda string
for ( int i = 0 ; i < ts ; i++ ) { // Para cada caractere da primeira string
    char cs = ts[i]; // Esse caractere precisa aparecer em v
    int apareceu = FALSO; // No começo, não apareceu (pois ainda não começamos a buscar)
    for ( int t = 0 ; t < tv ; t++ ) { // Para cada caractere da segunda string
        char cv = tv[t]; // Esse caractere será comparado a cs
        if ( cs == cv ) { // Apareceu!
            apareceu = VERDADEIRO;
            break; // Para de testar a segunda string, pois já achou o caractere
        }
    }
    if ( apareceu == FALSO ) // Se continua FALSO, é porque não apareceu
        return FALSO;
}
return VERDADEIRO; // Se passou por todos os caracteres da primeira string e nenhum
                   // deles retornou FALSO, então é porque todos aparecem na segunda
```

Obs.: Defini `VERDADEIRO` como `0` e `FALSO` como `-1`, como estabelecido na pergunta, mas esse é um modo bem pouco usual de se representar esses valores; normalmente se usa `0` como falso e qualquer coisa diferente de `0` como verdadeiro. A menos que tenha uma boa razão para desviar dessa convenção, sugiro que não o faça.

Comment: Parece-me muito bom o código @mgibsonbr. Obrigado pelos comentários em cada passo. Ajuda imenso :)

Comment: +1 pela observação acerca da convenção do C

Answer (score 3):

### **Atualização**

Segue um outro modo alternativo **sem** o uso a função [`strchr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/):

```c
int testarString(char *fonte, char encontrar[]){
    int i, ret = 0, tamanho = strlen(encontrar);
    while (*fonte){
        for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
            ret += ((*fonte == encontrar[i]) ? 1: 0);
        *fonte++;
    }
    return ((ret == tamanho) ? 0: 1);
}
```

Exemplo funcional no [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/TCy1hU).

---

Uma alternativa que pode ser utilizada é a função [`strchr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/), essa função retorna o ponteiro da primeira ocorrência de um caractere, ela recebe dois parâmetros, o primeiro é a *string* a ser percorrida, e o segundo, o caractere a ser encontrado.

A ideia é percorrer os caracteres da *string* a ser encontrada, no caso a variável `s`, e verificar se há correspondência na *string* a ser verificada, no caso, a variável `v`.

Isso pode ser implementado da seguinte forma:

```c
int testarString(char fonte[], char encontrar[]){
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= strlen(encontrar)){
        if (strchr(fonte, encontrar[i]) == 0)
            return 1;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Exemplo funcional no [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/36sHhy).

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução mais eficiente para esse problema involve ordenar as strings antes de começar a compará-las. Em pseudo código;

```
ss = sort(s) // "acb" vira "abc"
sv = sort(v) // "cdeabf" vira "abcdef"

//invariante: Os caracteres de ss[0,i) estão contidos em sv[0,j)
i = j = 0
while i < len(ss) do
    while j < len(sv) and ss[i] != sv[j] do
        j += 1
    done
    if j < len(sv) then
        i += 1  // achei um par para ss[i]
    else
        return NAO // ss[i] não tem par em v
    end
done

return SIM
```

A maioria das outras respostas apresentam algoritmos quadráticos, que levam um tempo proporcional ao tamanho de uma string mumltiplicado pelo tamanho da outra. O algoritmo que apresentei consiste em uma etapa de ordenação que leva tempo O(n log n) (ou O(n) se você usar um radix-sort da vida) seguida de uma etapa de comparação O(n) que faz apenas uma passada nas strings.